# Elegant way to work with 2D list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have just start with Python 2.7 for few months. I usually work with some 2D list in Python, simple task but I wonder that is there some more elegant way to do the same my job in Python 2.7?

Here is my task. I have a 2D list:

```
my_list = [["__cat_1", "__cat_2"],
           ["__cat_3", "__cat_4"]]
```

I want to convert the above 2D string list to 2D integer list.

```
expected_result = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

As usual, I do as the following:

```
def convert_2D_string_list(my_list):
    for a_group in my_list:
        yield [int(k.replace("__cat_","")) for k in a_group]
```

But the above could not work when my input has 3 dimensions like:

```
my_second_list = [[["__cat_1", "__cat_2"], "__cat_12"],
                  [["__cat_3", "__cat_4"], "__cat_34"]]
```

If my input list is `integer`, I know the elegant way to convert for transform it. For example:

```
def convert_2D_int_list:
    my_list = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
    import numpy as np
    # Assume that, I want to add 1 for each of element

    # Convert to numpy array
    my_list = np.asarray(my_list)
    my_list += 1

    # my_list = [[2, 3], [4, 5]]
    return my_list
```

What is the best practice for my `convert_2D_string_list` method? 
So in case of it is not 2D list, but 3D list -> I will not afraid about the number of dimensions.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: The important thing to understand is that lists do not have dimensions. Also, I would not call converting a list to an array elegant, if what you really want is a list. They are two different data structures with different use cases.

Comment: I would recommend using a recursive function.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You absolutely right. My list does not have dimensions. I just want to find a want to convert the multi-dimension array to the other form but keep the dimension. Maybe, "elegant" is not suitable here. Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: @VũTuấnAnh I don't understand if you are working with an array or a list. They are different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy array  works very well with NUMbers, it's a little more tricky with strings. [`np.vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) is a work around for such situation, even no performance improvement is done. But it manages any number of dimensions, hope you will find it elegant.

```
a=np.array([[[['__cat_0', '__cat_1'],
         ['__cat_2', '__cat_3']],

        [['__cat_4', '__cat_5'],
         ['__cat_6', '__cat_7']]],


       [[['__cat_8', '__cat_9'],
         ['__cat_10', '__cat_11']],

        [['__cat_12', '__cat_13'],
         ['__cat_14', '__cat_15']]]])


def f(str): return int(str[6:])        
fv=np.vectorize(f)

print(fv(a))
```

gives :

```
[[[[ 0  1]
   [ 2  3]]

  [[ 4  5]
   [ 6  7]]]


 [[[ 8  9]
   [10 11]]

  [[12 13]
   [14 15]]]]
```

Remark : `a` is `np.vectorize(lambda n : '__cat_'+str(n))(np.arange(16).reshape((2,)*4))` ;)

Comment: Sorry, maybe "elegant" is not exactly suitable in this case but it is exactly what I want. Thank you very much @B. M.

Comment: I can custom `f` function as needed. Add, replace, strim, etc. Awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Modify the values whilst recursively copying the list(s).

```
def visit(fn, xs):
    return [visit(fn, x) if isinstance(x, list) else fn(x) for x in xs]
```

in this case the modification function `fn` is something like:

```
    def categorize(s):
        return int(re.match(r'__cat_(\d*)', s).group(1))
```

testing this:

```
my_second_list = [[["__cat_1", "__cat_2"], "__cat_12"],
              [["__cat_3", "__cat_4"], "__cat_34"]]

print visit(categorize, my_second_list)
```

outputs:

```
> [[[1, 2], 12], [[3, 4], 34]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your string 2D list to int 2D list using map and list comprehensions

```
my_list = [["__cat_1", "__cat_2"],["__cat_3", "__cat_4"]]    
my_list = [map(lambda z: int(z.split('_')[-1]), ls) for ls in my_list]
print my_list # [[1,2],[3,4]]
```

3d list:

```
my_list = [["__cat_1", "__cat_2", '__cat_3'],["__cat_1", "__cat_2", '__cat_3']]
my_list = [map(lambda z: int(z.split('_')[-1]), ls) for ls in my_list]
print my_list # [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

Comment: Yes. It's can be another approach but not definitely what I want. I case of `my_list` could be 3 dimension list. It can't work. That why I think it not elegant.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not 3D. It's still 2D list. Please look at my question, I have just updated with an example of 3D list.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question, np.vectorize solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may useful for you:

`def con(x):
    # you can do here whatever u want
    return x.split('_')[-1]
y= [con(v) for v in my_list]`